# Missing Method Exception in Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe when calling constructor

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

I am using Visual Studio Community 2015 and trying to do the MSDN walkthrough on how to sync a SQL Server database with a local SQL Server Compact database.

Specifically I am getting a "Missing Method" exception when I try to build the `ProvisionClient` component of the walkthrough (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928765(v=sql.110).aspx)

The exact error is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in dnx.host.dll
>
> Additional information: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning..ctor(System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection, Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.DbSyncScopeDescription)'.

This is my code:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe;

namespace ProvisionClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // create a connection to the SyncCompactDB database
            SqlCeConnection clientConn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source='C:\proj\synctest\SyncSQLServerAndSQLCompact\SyncCompactDB.sdf'");

            // create a connection to the SyncDB server database
            SqlConnection serverConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SHRIMAD\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=SyncDB; Integrated Security=True");

            // get the description of ProductsScope from the SyncDB server database
            DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForScope("ProductsScope", serverConn);

            // create CE provisioning object based on the ProductsScope
            SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning clientProvision = new SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning(clientConn, scopeDesc);

            // starts the provisioning process
            clientProvision.Apply();

        }
    }
}
```

I have noticed that on the line:

```
// create CE provisioning object based on the ProductsScope
SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning clientProvision = new SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning(clientConn, scopeDesc);
```

If I call the constructor that only has the `scopeDesc`, then the exception does not show up, but then if I call the following `clientProvision.Apply` with the `clientConn`, then I get the missing method exception for the `Apply` line.

What am I doing wrong?  It looks like it does not want to accept a `clientConn` parameter, but without that it can not know what DB to provision.

TIA, this is my first post on StackOverflow!

Comment: are you using SQL CE 4?

Comment: yes, I am using SQL CE 4.0 and MS Sync Framework 2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sync Framework doesnt support SQL CE 4.0.

Have a look at the workaround i blogged [here](https://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/sync-framework-and-sql-compact-4-yes-you-can/) that uses binding redirects.

Comment: @abaustin did it work? I followed 15 tutorials now but all are outdated